# How do I implement IHttpClientFactory with DI for unittesting purposes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm currently using HttpClient in my constructor, but using interfaces seems to be a best-practice. Since an interface for HttpClient doesn't exist (IHttpClient), I'm wondering, how can I implement an interface for HTTPClient (for unittesting purposes)?

Comment: Any code? Anything you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit more convoluted than that. The "normal" way to do this is to create a dummy HttpClient and a class that inherits from `DelegatingHandler` and on its `SendAsync`, it doesn't actually send the request. There's some tutorials about this online